# XSLT display item

Tags: xslt

In the following XML, I would like only get the number 2 and 5 items,
how could it be done on XSLT?

```
<root>
    <content>item 1</content>
    <content>item 2</content>
    <content>item 3</content>
    <content>item 4</content>
    <content>item 5</content>
    <content>item 6</content>
</root>
```

Comment: XML does not have order defined on it (apart from document order), so a parser may reorder nodes at will. Why would you need to select nodes by position only?

Comment: The reason which we have a client system to generate ordered XML file for us

Comment: @Oded: In XML specification (http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/) there are no order definitions aside from content validation. Even does not contain the phrase "document order". In XPATH specification there are order definitions. In particular, navigation axes are with respect to document order, and `position()` follow the axis in scope. But it's not guaranteed that an expression that evaluate to a node set return this node set in any order. XSLT does guarantee for some instructions that a node set expression will be use in document order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="/root/content[2]" /> 
<xsl:value-of select="/root/content[5]" />
```

NOTE:

Oded is right but I think this is the best you can get